# Let $f(x)=2 x^{-3}$ for x between 1 and Infinity, $f(x)=0$ otherwise be the pdf for a random variable $X$, find $F(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $f(x)=2 x^{-3}$ for x between 1 and Infinity, $f(x)=0$ otherwise be the pdf for a random variable $X$, find $F(x)$.

Could you please help me how can I find it ?

Comment: Do you know how $F$ and $f$ are related in general?

Comment: I mean 1<x<Infinity

Comment: carmichael561 I know f(xi)=F(xi)-F(xi-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dx=\int_1^x\frac2{t^3}dt+...\;,\;\;t\ge1$$

Comment: It should be $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\;dt$ (I didn't downvote).

Comment: @carmichael561 Thank you, I shall edit. There seems to be a random downvoter in the house. Not the first time, though.